# Set Height of Inner RecyclerView wrap_content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview inside another recyclerview. I want to make height of inner recyclerview "warp_content".

I came to know it is possible with new version of recyclerview which is mentioned below.

```
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

But the problem is, by setting height = wrap_content I can see only first item.

Any Help will be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because I am using a `RecyclerView` this does not work see:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772

and

**Nested Recycler view height doesn't wrap it's content**

On both of these pages people suggest to extend `LinearLayoutManager` and to override `onMeasure()`

RecyclerView doesn't have the wrap_content by default. You have to use the RecyclerView with wrap_content Layout Manager such as, WrapLinearLayoutManager e.g CustomLinearLayoutManager .

> CustomLinearLayoutManager.java

```
    public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private static final String TAG = CustomLinearLayoutManager.class.getSimpleName();

public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {

    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, i, View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            mMeasuredDimension);


        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                           int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    try {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(0);//fix 动态添加时报IndexOutOfBoundsException

        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);

            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);

            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: How I can set it for Recyclerview.

Comment: in inner recyclerview setLayoutManager()

Comment: I'm doing this but getting index out of bound. 


MyLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new MyLinearLayoutManager(hostActivity);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Comment: I have updated the LayoutManger please look into this

Comment: Thanks for the help. This solution worked with Recyclerview version 23.1.0.

Comment: I was still getting the same result, height of 1 child. All I had to do is set the height of my child_item_layout to wrap_content

Comment: If you get index out of bound exception call setAutoMeasureEnabled(false); in the constructor of CustomLinearLayoutManager.

Answer (score 2):

Setting recyclerview item works for me.
 Outer wrapper relative layout is added intentionally to address issue `layout_height="wrap_content"` does NOT
                             occupy the height of all the elements added to it via adapter. The result is cut out
                             items that is outside of device viewport when it loads initially.
                             Wrapping "RecyclerView" with "RelativeLayout" fixes the issue on Marshmallow devices.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/test_item"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```